# users post count

Tags: custom-post-types, users, archives

I'm trying to set up users archive pages;

I notice that, if a user exists and is the owner of a custom post, it doesn't have an archive page;

so I looked inside user.php in order to include custom posts in the function `count_user_posts`,

the original function was

```php
function count_user_posts( $userid, $post_type = 'post', $public_only = false ) {}
```

and I changed it to

```php
function count_user_posts( $userid, $post_type = array('post','blog','lettura','intervista'), $public_only = false )
```

this didn't work, so I'm wondering where is the function that assigns archive pages to users

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The `count_user_posts` accepts array as the `$post_type` arguments. You don't need to include the `$post_type =` part.

```
$user_posts = count_user_posts( $userid, array('post','blog','lettura','intervista') );
```

The `$user_posts` variable will hold the number of posts for the `$userid`.

Comment: thank you so much, it reports
syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: @Enrico It shouldn't. Are you sure this is the line that produces the error? How are you getting the user ID?

Comment: yes, I'm sure :) this is the only row I edit on /wp-includes/user.php
`$post_type = ['post', 'blog', 'lettura', 'intervista']` this syntax is ok, but I haven't found the solution yet. It probably has to do with the _Co-authors plus_ plugin which manage users autorship

Comment: @Enrico You really shouldn't edit WordPress core files. My code goes into your theme's templates. It looks like you really need to know how WordPress works.